# Features of the Blender viewport

Tags: 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

I don't use Blender myself, and I was wondering if it's possible to "look up and down" in the viewport, like Quake? I know that EEVEE will let you "go in", ie. the UP key in Quake, but it would be really cool if you could look up and down as well. If it's not there, could someone suggest it to the devs? :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You can enter Walk Navigation mode and control the camera like it's usual in games with <kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> keys and mouse.

[image]

If you look at the status bar while in that mode, you can see all the hotkeys the modal operator has:

[image]

So it's even possible to turn on gravity if you have ground in your scene.

You could right-click the menu item and assign a hotkey to it for easy access, or add it to your Quick Favourites menu(<kbd>Q</kbd>). I believe it used to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>F</kbd> by default many many versions ago, or maybe it was for Fly mode, but anyway, that hotkey is free, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> for walk maybe. These will not conflict with anything else in Blender by default, but it can be anything you want obviously.

If you wanted arrow keys, that might get a bit complicated, but it's possible with Python. But, yes, it's a bit more tricky and one might need to write some custom operators for that.

Comment: Sorry, W A S D is for in and backwards etc. right? They're not for "looking up and down"??

Comment: No, the mouse is for looking around. Like in computer games. The arrow keys actually work for walking as well. If you wanted to turn the camera around with arrow keys, you would have to do some somewhat complicated scripting('complicated' keeping in mind you don't use Blender and are new to this, it's doable with Python)

Comment: Oh, cool! :) Thanks!